# Different size items in simmer queue

Tags: r, simulation

I'm starting out learning the simmer package for discrete event simulation, but can't figure out how to have different size items in a queue.

For example, if we have vehicles entering a queue, a bus is going to take up a lot more space than a motorbike. Is there a way of specifying how many queue spaces an item occupies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a vignette](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-07-ctmc.html) that discusses this kind of things. TL;DR: you can seize more than one element, among other options.